# Sort by condition input with ArrayList Android

Tags: android

I have a arraylist with two field Name and Year. I want to sort this array with condition input name (sort by name input). If the name is same it will sort by year.

```
Example
Name     Year
Ann      2000
Bech     2001
Bach     2013
Bach     2012
Chu      1999
```

Assume that I create a function is sort with input is Bach. The result will display

```
Name     Year
Bach     2013
Bach     2012
Ann      2000
Bech     2001
Chu      1999
```

Because with input is Bach and the first I want to display all name with "Bach" If the same name I will sort it by year(largest-smallest). If don't same "Bach" name I will sort by A-Z using compareTo()
This is my code but I don't have input condition name . Please make a new function help me same sort_inputname(String inputname)

```
    //Class compare Name- Year
public class Search_Name_Year_Comparator implements Comparator<SearchListInformation>
{


            public int compare(SearchListInformation left,
                    SearchListInformation right) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 int dateComparison;
                    int dataComparison = 0;
        if(left.getName().compareTo(right.getName())==0)
            {
             if(left.getYear().compareTo(right.getYear())>0)
             {
             return -1;
             }
             else if(left.getYear().compareTo(right.getYear())<0)
             {
                 return  1;
             }
             else 
                 return 0;


             }
        else
         return  left.getName().compareTo(right.getName());
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit hard to understand your question (I assume you are not a native English speaker, but you can't be blamed for that). From what I understand, you want to sort an ArrayList of objects that have 2 properties : Name and Year. Let's just assume those objects are called "SearchListInformation", so you're trying to sort an ArrayList of SearchListInformation.

What I would do here is make the SearchListInformationclass implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) (not Comparator) interface (see the link for more information).
Then you can juste use Collections.sort to sort your ArrayList, for instance :

```
    ArrayList<SearchListInformation> list = new ArrayList<SearchListInformation>();
    list.add(new Person("Bob", 2000));
    list.add(new Person("Lucy", 2010));
    Collections.sort(list);
```

If you want to use the Comparator interface, you can also use Collections.sort(List, Comparator). Then you can use the code you posted, but I would simplify it this way :

```
    @Override
    public int compare(SearchListInformation left, SearchListInformation right) {
        if(left.getName().compareTo(right.getName())==0)
             return -1*left.getYear().compareTo(right.getYear())
        else
            return  left.getName().compareTo(right.getName());
    }
```

Edit : If you want to be able to specify a name that should be always at the beginning of the list, you should use the second option : implement the Comparator interface like this :

```
    public MyComparator implements Comparator<SearchListInformation> {

        protected String _priorityName;

        public MyComparator(String priorityName) {
            _priorityName = priorityName;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(SearchListInformation left, SearchListInformation right) {
            if(left.getName().compareTo(right.getName())==0)
                 return -1*left.getYear().compareTo(right.getYear())
            else if(left.getName().equals(_priorityName)
                return -1;
            else if(right.getName().equals(_priorityName)
                return 1;
            else
                return  left.getName().compareTo(right.getName());
        }

    }
```

Then you can use :

```
    Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator("Bach"));
```

Comment: You don't understand my question. My question is sort by name input. Not A->Z. Assume that I have name A, B,C,D. I want to sort with name input =B. That means the result will B, A,C,D. Can you help me?

Comment: You're welcome ; don't forget to mark the question as answered if you got all you needed.